# Input not binding to model

Tags: angularjs

I have an input box and my model is undefined for somereason when I try to access it in controller. 
Below is the input box

```
<input type="text" ng-if="primaryOperator == 'Age'"
                            ng-model="primaryValueData" placeholder="enter Value"
                            class="hideOutlineClass" />
```

when i try to access $scope.primaryValueData in controller it is undefined. I cannot use ng-show have to use ng-if. Any help is appreciated

Comment: show us the controller please

Comment: what @CharlieNg said. + make a code snippet...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
<div ng-if="primaryOperator === 'Age'">
<input type="text" 
ng-model="primaryValueData" placeholder="enter Value"
class="hideOutlineClass" />
</div>
```